# How to search for ID in array of objects not using a for loop?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I know that I can search this array of objects by using a for loop and if statement,

```
var junkData = [
        { "ID": "1", "AreaName": "Area A Tester" },
        { "ID": "2", "AreaName": "Area B Test" },
        { "ID": "3", "AreaName": "Area C" },
        { "ID": "4", "AreaName": "Area D 12" },
        { "ID": "5", "AreaName": "Area E" }
];
```

but which other ways are available to me? I would like to search on the ID and then return that object. 
So if I wanted to search for ID 3, then it would return the object whose ID is 3.

What other options are available outside of using a for loop with an if statement?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`Array#find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) instead:

```js
var junkData = [
        { "ID": "1", "AreaName": "Area A Tester" },
        { "ID": "2", "AreaName": "Area B Test" },
        { "ID": "3", "AreaName": "Area C" },
        { "ID": "4", "AreaName": "Area D 12" },
        { "ID": "5", "AreaName": "Area E" }
];

console.log(junkData.find(e => e.ID == 3))
```

Answer (score 2):

You can filter the results.

```js
var junkData = [
  { "ID": "1", "AreaName": "Area A Tester" },
  { "ID": "2", "AreaName": "Area B Test" },
  { "ID": "3", "AreaName": "Area C" },
  { "ID": "4", "AreaName": "Area D 12" },
  { "ID": "5", "AreaName": "Area E" }
];

console.log(findBy(junkData, 'ID', '2', true));

function findBy(arr, key, val, onlyOne) {
  return (ret => onlyOne ? ret.shift() : ret)(arr.filter(item => item[key] === val));
}
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }
```

The `ret` is the return of the filtered results (in the right parenthesis). I wrapped it in a self-returning function. You could also just assign the filtered results to a variable before returning.

Comment: Though this is a good approach, its gonna take time for any reader to understand whats going on... Also, if `onlyOne` is true, it makes more sense to use `array.find` instead.

Comment: can you explain what is `ret` in findBy function?

Comment: @noobie I added a blurb at the bottom.